# How to display a popup message at the time of page closing

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

Using ASP.Net, VB.Net

When i close or exit the page, it should show the pop up message like "page closing"

Need code help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit() {
            return "You want to leave this page?";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think that will work if the user clicks on the x or tries to navigate away.  That sample just shows how to show a confirmation dialog on a button click.  The button in the example is a standard html button, not the browser's close button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onunload="event.returnValue = 'Check?';">
```

That's also pretty much the code that's used if you start typing an answer here and try to close or navigate away.  ;-)

Here's an answer at another forum as well.  http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/16890-code-showing-you-sure-you-want-navigate-away-page.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a jQuery popup message that fires at the time of page closing

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    return inFormOrLink || confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link which can show you the sample code to show the message when the page is closed/Exited.

http://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/window-onbeforeunload-javascript-code/

You can also further call the serverside methods using ajax in Javascript functions.
The examples are present on the following linkS:
http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1